# Copy a table and define the primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `temp_element` generated with .to_sql (method of Pandas). I want to copy it and define column `id_element` as the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE element AS
SELECT * FROM temp_element,
PRIMARY KEY id_element;
```

This doesn't work. Why? I'm using SQLite so can't use `ALTER TABLE` to define primary keys afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sqlite this doesn't seem to be possible.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/primary_keys.php#:%7E:text=The%20syntax%20to%20add%20a,pk_col1%2C%20pk_col2%2C%20

> If your table already exists and you wish to add a primary key later, you can not use the ALTER TABLE statement to create a primary key. Instead, you must create a new table with the primary key and copy the data into this new table.

You'd have to create the table with its primary key, then insert the data into it.

`INSERT INTO element SELECT * FROM temp_element;`